# im using dart 2.16.2 Raisedbutton onpressed Change page no affect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i want to changed my page when i press my RaisedButton.

**here's my code :**

```
Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(56, 0, 56, 24),          

child: RaisedGradientButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserDetailPage()),
                );
                // ignore: avoid_print
                print("Button Click");
              },
              child: Text(
                'Got It',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Nunito',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: const <Color>[Colors.purple, Colors.blue],
              ),
)

)
```

My model not change to page, Please help me.

Preview error no Affect with click

[image]

Comment: Is your Padding widget inside of a materialApp?

Comment: yess.. im using padding material app..

Comment: but in case there is nothing wrong, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the following code in your RaisedGradientButton.dart

```
InkWell(
            onTap: () => onPressed,
            child: Center(
              child: child,
            )),
```

With:

```
  InkWell(
            onTap: onPressed,
            child: Center(
              child: child,
            )),
```

Be aware that if you have functions in your widget's parameters you should always use "() =>" either where you built your widget or where you use your widget only once.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I really appreciate your help. and i have added, final VoidCallback onPressed; Success